# Can I sort vector of tuple of references?

Tags: sorting, c++11, tuples

When following code:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int&>> v;
int a = 5; v.emplace_back(a);
int b = 4; v.emplace_back(b);
int c = 3; v.emplace_back(c);
int d = 2; v.emplace_back(d);
int e = 1; v.emplace_back(e);
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

is compiled with gcc/libstdc++ vs clang/libc++ binary gives different results.

For [gcc/libstdc++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fxMX0ZyHqqMrWcF5) one element is copied to all the other references.

```
5 4 3 2 1 
5 5 5 5 5
```

First I thought that [clang/libc++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0sXSldaaVVpR2kfR) behaves *as expected* but it only works up to 5 elements in a vector (cause there is a special case for small containers).

```
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```

When passing more elements result is similar to gcc.

```
5 4 3 2 1 0 
3 4 5 5 5 5
```

So is it valid to use `std::sort` for container of tuples with references (i.e. made with `std::tie`, sorting subset of struct)?
If not, should I expect any warnings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So is it valid to use `std::sort` for container of tuples with references (i.e. made with `std::tie`, sorting subset of struct)? If not, should I expect any warnings?

No, and no. One of the type requirements on [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is that:

> - The type of dereferenced `RandomIt` must meet the requirements of `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`.

where [`MoveAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable) requires in the expression `t = rv`:

> The value of `t` is **equivalent** to the value of `rv` before the assignment.

But `std::tuple<int&>` isn't MoveAssignable because `int&` isn't MoveAssignable. If you simply have:

```
int& ra = a;
int& rb = b;

ra = std::move(rb);
```

The value of `ra` isn't equivalent to the prior value of `rb`. `ra` still *refers* to `a`, it does not change to refer to `b` - what actually changed was the value of `a`.

Since our type doesn't meet the precondition of `std::sort()`, the result of the `std::sort()` call is just undefined behavior.

---

Note that you *could* sort a `std::vector<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<int>>>` though, because [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) is MoveAssignable.

Note also that this is reminiscent of not being able to sort a container of `auto_ptr`, per an old Herb Sutter [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm).

Comment: Using `std::reference_wrapper<int>` works cause it can be constructed from `std::tie` but requires some template magic to get T&... type list and decorate it with reference_wrapper.

[Both compilers](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/atQyUIr1Bh5g6qgn) agree that `std::tuple<int&>` is_move_assignable && is_move_constructible (with the standard traits)

Comment: @KarolWozniak The trait can only check if the actual semantic works - you *can* move assign a `tuple<int&>`. It just doesn't have the actual behavior that that operation needs to have in order to be considered MoveAssignable.

Comment: @KarolWozniak For instance, `struct X { int val; X& operator=(X&& ) { return *this; };` `is_move_assignable<X>` is true, but `X` isn't actually MoveAssignable since the requirement isn't met.

Comment: I can consider replacing `std::tie` with `my_own::tie_wrapper`, that would solve my original problem in elegant way,
thanks!